# How can I get AutoHotKey to open a ClickOnce (.appref-ms) file?

Tags: autohotkey, clickonce

I'm using [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) and would like to use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to map Alt+G to the Git Shell shortcut that is installed on the desktop.

With this in my `.ahk` file it gives me the error "Failed attempt to launch program or document"

```
!g::Run C:\Users\dennis\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell
```

`.appref-ms` has something to do with ClickOnce, but I don't know why AutoHotKey can't open it. Is it just not compatible with the `Run` command, or is there something else I need to do to make this work?

**Edit:** The same line minus the `--open-shell` parameter works, but I don't need the GUI. Maybe my issue has more to do with how to pass command line arguments within AutoHotKey.

Comment: Try this: `!g::Run, C:\Users\dennis\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell, C:\Users\dennis\AppData\Local\GitHub\ return`

Comment: @PeterMaxwell that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the desktop shortcut did the trick!

```
!g::Run "C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\Git Shell"
```